# how to get count for terminated threads?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-7

hello friends i have a doubt regarding thread count. i have some code written below for thread

```
Procedure Mainthread.execute;
 var
    I  :    integer;
    ScannerCh : array  of ScannerChild;  //array of ScannerChild
  IpList : TStringlist;
  IPs: Integer;   //ipcount is count of iplist
Begin
       IpList:=TStringList.Create;//creating stringlist
       IPs := IpList.Count; //Ipcount is given value of iplists count
       SetLength(ScannerCh, IPs);  //Setting length of scannerch as ipcount
       I:=0;
        Repeat
          While getthreadscount(getcurrentprocessid) >= tcount + 1(for main thread + Scannerch threads) do  //Checking if  is greater than tcount(thread input) by user
            Sleep(30);
          ScannerCh[I]:=ScannerChild.Create(True, IpList[i]);
          ScannerCh[I].FreeOnTerminate:=True;

          ScannerCh[I].LvHostname := LvHosts;
          ScannerCh[I].Resume;

          I:=I+1;
          Sleep(20);   //Sleep after each thread is created so that threads will enter critical section properly
       until I = IPs;
 end;
```

Scannerchild thread does some work. my code works perfectly if i have only these threads in process. If there are some other threads running to then i will be in trouble getting threadscount by getthreadscount function and i will not get to know which threads are getting terminated by getthreadcount function. so how can i enhance my code for many threads working. My logic is when scannerch thread terminates it should decrement count variable and when it gets created it should increment count variable. so that it will not be any problem if other threads are terminated or not. i just want to deal with scannerch thread termination and need to get counts of instances of running threads of scannerch. so that i put count variable instead of getthreadscount and my problem will be solved

Comment: I have heard of TNotifyEvent but dont know how to use it

Comment: Seriously?  The Button1Click method of form is an example of a  TNotifyEvent.  Look it up in the OLH.  In Delphi, you can define your own event types if you want.

Comment: @MartynA +1 But most beginners *know* the `TNotifyEvent` only from double click the control and magically getting a method declaration ;o)

Comment: @MartynA- sir i know what it is but just want to use here..like onterminate := some procedure called deccount  and in deccount dec(count) and declare deccount procedure  as tnotifyevent

Comment: You did not declare a method as a `TNotifyEvent`. The method has to have the same structure as described by `TNotifyEvent` and can then be used as a handler for this.

Comment: Define a method `procedure Mainthread.ScanchildTerminated( Sender : TObject );` and do there what you want. To assign this method just assign it `ScannerCh[i].OnTermenate = Self.ScanchildTerminated;`. The `Sender` argument contains the reference of the ScannerChild instance

Comment: And did this method has an argument `Sender : TObject`? If not, this method did not have the structure as described by `TNotifyEvent`!

Comment: You really are doing this all wrong. Rather than me repeating myself, you should follow the advice I gave in your previous question.

Comment: @SirRufo thank you so much sir and sorry for silly question. concept is cleared now

Comment: Surely IPs will be zero because it is a count if the number of items in a string list that has just been created. So ScannerCh will have a length 0 and any attempt to write to it will fail. But I agree with David, this really is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: @SirRufo:  Indeed.  But the difference between knowing of and understanding seems to be quite a gulf, as was instantly demonstrated by the comment "I know what it is ..."  Oh, well ...

Comment: What you do is create N threads. Populate a threadsafe list with the tasks to be performed. Have each thread pull of and perform tasks. When there are no tasks left the threads can quit. A simple thread pool. You don't even need a proper threadsafe list. Just a shared index of the next task and an atomic increment function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question is easy enough to answer. Declare a count variable in the main thread class:

```
FScannerChildCount: Integer;
```

Whenever you create a new thread, increment this variable. Whenever a thread terminates, decrement it.

The incrementing is easy to do since you create the threads quite clearly and explicitly in the main thread code.

As for the decrementing, you need an `OnTerminate` event handler for each scanner child thread instance. This executes in the context of the process main thread, rather than your `MainThread` thread. FWIW, `MainThread` is a terrible name since everyone takes main thread to mean the main process thread. Because the `OnTerminate` event doesn't run in the same thread as your `MainThread` thread, you'll need synchronization.

When you increment the thread, use `InterlockedIncrement`. And when you decrement, use `InterlockedDecrement`.

The `OnTerminate` handler might look like this:

```
procedure MainThread.ScannerChildTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InterlockedDecrement(FScannerChildCount);
end;
```

And you assign the event like any other event handler:

```
ScannerCh[I] := ...;
....
ScannerCh[I].OnTerminate := ScannerChildTerminate;
....
ScannerCh[I].Resume;
```

All of this said, whilst this may be the answer to the question you asked, you are attempting to solve your problem the wrong way. You should be using a thread pool to simplify the coding and avoid the overhead of creating and destroying short lived threads.